# Al iterar array asociativo me aparece una coma

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

estoy iterando un array asociativo para devolver un objeto html con propiedades de configuración de un objeto JSON, y cuando termina cada iteración introduce una coma. He revisado el código varias veces y no encuentro el error, solo aparece a partir de la primera iteracción.

```
const boton_content = [{
    nombre: 'button',
    class: 'botonText',
    texto: 'Texto del boton',
    type: 'text',
}, {
    nombre: 'button',
    class: 'botonText2',
    texto: 'Soy el texto el boton2',
    type: 'text',
},
{
    nombre: 'button',
    class: 'botonText2',
    texto: 'Soy el texto el boton3',
    type: 'text',
}, 
{
    nombre: 'button',
    class: 'botonText2',
    texto: 'Soy el texto el boton',
    type: 'text',
}];


const t_settings_content_button = function() {
    var result = [];

    for (var property in boton_content) {
        result[property] = (`
    <div class="lib-field" id="lib-settings_content_button>
    <label class="` + boton_content[property]['class'] + `">` + boton_content[property]['texto'] + ` </label>
    <input type=` + boton_content[property]['type'] + `>
    
    </div>
    `);
    }

    return result;

}
```

Podéis ver el problema en la siguiente captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde otro archivo tengo un función que lo agrega mediante jQuery de esta forma:

```
      var tab = $('#lib_sidebar_settings-tabs-content');
        
        tab.append($([{}].map(t_settings_content_button).join('')));
```

¿Alguien puede indicarme el error?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta. Perdón.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let a = [{}].map(t_settings_content_button);
```

Al ejecutar eso se crea un arreglo que en su interior contiene el arreglo retornado por la función `t_settings_content_button`, con la siguiente forma:

```
[
  [
    "elemento html1",
    "elemento html2"
  ]
]
```

La función `join('')` afecta al arreglo en el cual se llama, en este caso el arreglo externo, convirtiendo al arreglo interno en una cadena, donde cada elemento se separa por comas: `"elemento1, elemento2"`. Por eso las comas no desaparecen.

Para que funcione primero se debe usar la función `flat()` para combinar el sub arreglo dentro del arreglo principal y luego aplicar el `join()`.

```
let a = [{}].map(t_settings_content_button).flat().join('');
```

Otra forma sería aplicar directamente el `join()` en el arreglo devuelto por la función y el resultado pasarlo al `append()`.

```
tab.append(t_settings_content_button().join(''));
```